# Java - Issues using "throws IOException" in Netbeans with button click event

Tags: java, netbeans

## Background:

I am fairly new to the world of Java programming and the Netbeans IDE so apologies if this is a simple question to most people.

However, I am looking to run the following code when a button is clicked:

```
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnValue == fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        Scanner InFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    while(InFile.hasNext())
    {
    String string1 = InFile.next();
  
    System.out.print(" " + string1);
    }
```

The issue is that in order for this code to run correctly, I believe it requires `throws IOException`  after the deceleration of the method?

So.... in Netbeans I have created a mouse click event and the following has been created for me:

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
```

But... I need it to be this instead:

`private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) throws IOException {`

The problem is that Netbeans seems to have this section of code set to some sort of READ-ONLY and I am not able append the required code.

## Question:

Therefore, my question is simple. How do I add the `throws IOException` code where it needs to be?

Comment: Sounds like you're using some GUI builder so it generates the code for you? That's what it gets you, you can't modify the generated code (apparently). You'll have to use try/catch inside the method instead.

Comment: I am indeed using Netbeans to help create the GUI as I am very new to the Java language. How would I set up the Try Catch code in this case?

Comment: I don't understand why you need the method signature changed, since (I think) the NetBeans Form Editor is capable of allowing you to add custom code within the function definition.  And I don't know where you think IOException is being thrown from.

Comment: Google for try/catch, read tutorials, you're trying to program advanced things without knowing the basics, that's not a good idea. You'll be stuck every 5 minutes.

Comment: It is required for the FileReader to work correctly otherwise it won't build. @Kayaman I have read as much as I can but I learn best by doing but thank you very much for the heads up. I know how to set up a Try Catch just wasn't 100% which way to put the code.

Comment: @Kayaman The try/catch has worked - If you write it as an answer I will happily accept it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use try/catch clause inside the method instead of the throws clause.

```
try {
  JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
  if (returnValue == fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
      File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
      Scanner InFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
  while(InFile.hasNext()) {
      String string1 = InFile.next();
      System.out.print(" " + string1);
  }
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  // or handle in some other way
}
```

I would also advise against using GUI builders, or at least trying to create a GUI by hand. The builders may allow you to click around to create things, but they're not used usually in serious projects (generated code becomes very messy). Also, if you only use a GUI builder, you won't learn how Swing really works.